# How would I get this code to be executed without using stdlib.h

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, warnings

I keep receiving an error regarding malloc and I'm trying to find out how to get this code to work without using stdlib.h in the header. Just stdio.h, is this possible and how? As I'm totally confused

```
#include <stdio.h>

void allocate(int* score_array, const int input)
{
    int iter;

    for(iter = 1;iter <= 11;++iter)
    {
        if( (input < iter*10) && (input >= (iter-1)*10 ) )
        {
            ++(score_array[iter-1]);
        }
    }
}

void printf_star(const int len)
{
    int iter;

    for(iter = 0;iter < len;++iter)
    {
        printf("*");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int iter, size, temp;
    int* buffer;
    int score_array[11];

    for(iter = 0;iter < 11;++iter)
    {
        score_array[iter] = 0;
    }

    printf("How many grades will you be entering?\n");
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    buffer = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    for(iter = 1;iter <= size;++iter )
    {
        printf("Getting grade %d. You have %d grade(s) left to enter\n", iter, size-iter+1);
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp);

        if( (temp>=0) && (temp <= 100) )
        {
            buffer[iter-1] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                printf("Invalid Value!\n");
                printf("Getting grade %d. You have %d grade(s) left to enter\n", iter, size-iter+1);
                printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
            }
            while( (temp < 0) || (temp > 100) );
        }
    }

    for(iter = 1;iter <= size;++iter)
    {
        allocate(score_array, buffer[iter-1]);
    }

    for(iter = 0;iter < 11;++iter)
    {
        printf_star(score_array[iter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
hw08.c: In function ‘main’:
hw08.c:56: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
```

Comment: Why **don't** you want to use the stdlib.h header? `malloc` **is** defined in the standard library header!

Comment: Professor does not want us using it

Comment: [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) *requires* `stdlib.h` inclusion. Whatever mysterious error you're receiving doesn't change that fact.

Comment: `malloc` is declared in `stdlib.h` so if for whatever (stupid) reason you may not include `stdlib.h` then you may not use `malloc`.

Comment: @CoffeeMug Wauw! That's surprising! Maybe your professor wants you to use a custom header file and include stdlib in there! I don't see any other way(unless you copy-paste the malloc and it's dependencies in your local file)...

Comment: Let's ask another question: are you *required* to use `malloc`?

Comment: My crystal ball is nudging me to suggest your prof wants you to use an (ill-advised) VLA (variable-length array) for this rather than heap-allocation. That would *not* require `malloc` or `free`, and would lift the corresponding mandate for `stdlib.h`. In short, this may very well be an XY problem.

Comment: It would be extremely odd for your professor to forbid you to include the `stdlib.h` header, yet accept your use of any of the functions declared in it.  You would be well advised to ask her about that -- either she will tell you what to do about `malloc()`, or she will tell you that you must not use it.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think you're exactly right considering she keeps harping on arrays in class now, Thanks!

Comment: Given you're only expecting to have at most 100 values, you could just define an array of that size...and also make sure that the number entered is within the right range too.

Comment: @CoffeeMug Chris is probably correct on the intended goal of this. If your prof said "use `malloc`" and "don't use `stdlib.h`" they're a nitwit. If they simply said "don't use `stdlib.h`" they are *likely* inferring "don't use anything in `stdlib.h`", which is certainly doable in your program by either using VLAs or by using a known-fixed array and doing proper boundary checking to ensure it isn't breached (which you should do anyway, even with VLAs). You may want to get some clarification from your prof.

Comment: @WhozCraig why exactly are VLAs ill-advised?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a warning, not an actual error, so the program still compiles.

To eliminate the warning you can declare the malloc in your file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void * malloc(unsigned long);
```

You could also just include stdlib.h, unless you have a major reason not to.

Comment: It's definitely a compile ERROR and not a warning because the compiler cannot compile the source files without the function definition.

Comment: test.c:43:52: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                                    buffer = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));               I just compiled and ran that code with gcc.  It's a warning, and the program runs fine.

Comment: These tricks are definitely not what the professor meant (well, if he did - he is an idiot). So someone have just misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: _Your_ code may be giving off a compiler warning, but OP's code will straight up not compile and emit an error message because of a missing #include.

Comment: If you read the OP's post, you can clearly see the compiler warning:    hw08.c: In function ‘main’:
hw08.c:56: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

Comment: Additional comment: I just checked your answer. It's simply wrong. While the error message itself will go away using VC++ you will still receive a linking error because of unresolved externals.

Comment: Thanks KUSH42.  I guess that Visual C++ doesn't automatically link with the C Runtime?  Odd, but not all compilers are the same.

Comment: @KUSH42 *"OP's code will straight up not compile"* - the OP's code, sent *verbatim* through a language-standard compliant **C** toolchain, *will* compile, but do so with warnings (unless warnings-as-errors are mandated). [See example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9f25fc3b7f79194). Regardless, we can certainly agree that this is *not* the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: I just ran it on linux:`#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern void * malloc(size_t);
extern void free(void *);

int
main(void)
{
   char *cp;
   
   cp = malloc(5);
   strcpy( cp, "hell");
   printf("%s\n", cp);
   free(cp);
   return 0;
}`  I got hell as the output.

Comment: if malloc() and free() are defined in stdlib.h, how did this happen?  Should I move onto different language?  Is C stable?  (00)

Comment: Implicit function declarations are treated as errors since C99. While they were treated as warning before that, they really shouldn't be. AFAIK this is a known problem with gcc and can be 'fixed' by compiling with the `-Werror` option.

Comment: C is stable, @Nguaial.  C++ has a different definition of stability. Trying to use C++ compilers to compile C leads to problems.  Roll on C++20.

Comment: C is VERY stable.  It has been around for a long time.  Malloc and Free are defined in stdlib.h, but the actual binary implementation is in the libc library.  This also contains printf, strcpy, etc...  Therefore, the binary of malloc() would be linked to your program, and executed (possibly incorrectly) since you are overriding it's definition

Comment: @Nguai al This did happen because C treats it as an implicit function declaration without the include. It's just how the language is defined. But this is programmer error, not the language's fault. C is absolutely usable and stable, especially considering that most modern software builds its foundation on it, like Windows or Java.

Comment: @KUSH42 - I just tried with -Werror.  It didn't spit out any error/warning messages.

Comment: @KUSH42 No, this is not an error, this is a builtin function. The compiler knows about it and the code will work because it is linked by default. This is in fact the correct answer! The point here is that you copy only whats relevant from _stdlib.h_ instead of the whole file.

Comment: @ChrisRouffer - If malloc() is only defined in stdlib.h and the code only has `extern void * malloc(size_t);`, wouldn't this be a simple case compilation error since the actual definition of malloc() isn't present?  It shouldn't even advance to linking phase. This is very confusing.  Sorry.  (00)

Comment: Compiler doesn't really care. Defining it this way will tell the compiler not to worry about the function and use a placeholder instead, which is then supposed to get replaced during the linking phase by the actual function.

Comment: @Nguaial the implementation of malloc is in libc which is linked by default. It is thus present. The header only has the prototype which in turn only helps the compiler detecting possible errors because it hints what the function parameters are and what it returns. This is just a "help" for the compiler, not a must. That's why it is a warning, not error. Because the compiler faced an unknown function so it doesn't know if your usage is correct. None of this prevents compilation and linking. C is very simple to understand :)

Comment: @ChrisRouffer please use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long` to make it portable. `size_t` is available in `stddef.h`

Answer (score 1):

Header files just define the functions prototypes by using the `extern` keyword. The actual implementation of malloc resides in libc depending on the OS.

Not defining a function/system call prototype is **indeed** a warning, not a compile-time error, contrary to what many have conveyed in the comments!

[image]

Coming to the actual workaround, if you want to avoid using the `#include <stdlib.h>`, you either need to use:

1. `#include <malloc.h>` (***deprecated since c89***)
2. Define the header all by yourself, with `extern void * malloc(size_t);`

Credits to @Chris Rouffer too!  :)

Comment: `malloc.h` is deprecated and shouldn't be included anywhere anymore. `malloc.h` hasn't been part of the C standard since C89.

Comment: @KUSH42 Correct!

Comment: Using `unsigned long` as parameter for `malloc` is not very portable. Should use `size_t` which is available in `stddef.h`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Oh yes. I'd just copied this from Chris' answer. That's true, size_t is the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `stdlib.h` if you want to access the `malloc()` function, because that is where it is defined. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what to do. 
You really are supposed to include the header in your code if you want to use the function, however, in theory you could just paste the implementation of `malloc()` in your source and then use it from there without the header. This is a bad idea however, since anybody looking at the code would expect `malloc()` to refer to the standard implementation defined in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: you clearly don't understand the difference of a header and the actual implementation. The header contains no implementation, he doesn't need to implement it again. Just declare the function to eliminate the warning. That's what the header does. Either way it will work because the program gets linked to libc by default. That's where the implementation is. Again: _"you're supposed to include the header if you want to use the function"_ **No.** You're supposed to declare a function that you will use. Whether you'll do that by including a header or on your own doesn't matter.

Comment: Nowhere did I mention that the implementation of malloc() is in the header file. I literally wrote that the header contains the declaration of the function-prototype. And yes you, are supposed to include the header file if you want to use the function, because that is where its prototype is declared. Copy-pasting function declarations manually instead of including a header is a terrible practice.

Comment: You cannot copy paste the implementation of malloc. Malloc needs to make system calls which you cannot without other parts of stdlib. Unless you want to insert inline assembly, which would make it not portable.